# How to get the suggest attached to the text input?

Tags: javascript, html, combobox, webix, suggestbox

I know I can get the list within the Webix ui.combo's suggest as

```
var list = $$("combo").getPopup().getList();
```

And then use the list's API.

But how to do the same for the suggest attached to the text input (ui.text)? In other words, is it possible to get the suggest's object/list if I don't know its ID, but the needed text input is known?

For example

```
{ 
  view:"text", id:"txt", 
  value:"opt1", suggest:["opt1", "opt2"]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

var l = webix.$$(txt.config.suggest).getList();

where "txt" is is a reference to your webix.ui.text object.